# When we use global indexes and when we use local indexes in Oracle?

Tags: oracle11g, table-index

Can anybody explain me

When should we use **global indexes** ?

When should we use **local indexes** ?

Which **indexes** needs to be **dropped** before loading into table ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which indexes needs to be dropped before loading into table ?

- The unique ones. According to Oracle's documentation there is no way how to bulk-load data into table, having PK, UK constraints disabled and unique indexes invalidated. Even if you do both (disabling, invalidation) you will get ORA- error in insert anyway. The "official" recommendation is really to drop UK indexes before the load. And re-create the index afterwards.

Comment: When should we use global indexes ?

When should we use local indexes ?

Comment: It's not really easy to tell. Maybe you will find something useful in "Oracle Database Data Warehousing Guide"